# Why is it possible to modify a static const variable that is declared inside a function?

Tags: c++, entity-component-system

I'm implementing an ECS framework for my game engine and investigating ways to identify component types at runtime. This means I can dynamically group components of a similar type contiguously in memory. For example, I can have two separate arrays for `Position` and `Velocity` components that my systems can loop over.

I currently use `typeid()`, but I came across an article that uses `static const` variables to generate unique IDs for each type. The general idea can be summarized in the code snippet below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Position { float x, y; };
struct Velocity { float dx, dy; };

template <typename T>
int test(int x) {
    static const int y = x;
    return y;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << test<Position>(1) << " ";
    std::cout << test<Position>(2) << " ";
    std::cout << test<Velocity>(3) << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `1 1 3`, but I would expect that since it's attempting to modify a constant (specifically at the second call), it would fail to compile. Why does this work?

Comment: Interesting that C++ allows this (even without the template), considering that C does not.

Comment: "... since it's attempting to modify a constant..."  It's not.  Add in `y = x;`, and then the compiler will complain.

Comment: @Eljay Ah, I was confused because I thought that since the static variable survives after the function call, it would be illegal to declare it again, just as if you were to do `static const int x = 3; static const int x = 4;` in the global scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static variables are only initialized once.

The second (and consequent) time the initialization is skipped.

Here also you have 2 different functions `test`. 1 for each unique template parameter type.

An example, for a simple function call of Your code:

```
auto f() { return test<Position>(1); }
```

This will result in the following assembler code, where You can see that there is a check to verify if the variable has been already initialized or return the already set value. If it has not been set, then it will be set in a thread-safe manner.

```apollo
f():
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR guard variable for int test<Position>(int)::y[rip]
        test    al, al   // <----- check if intialized
        je      .L13     // <----- if not initialized go to .L13
                         // otherwise return the value
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR int test<Position>(int)::y[rip]
        ret
.L13:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:guard variable for int test<Position>(int)::y
        call    __cxa_guard_acquire
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L14
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR int test<Position>(int)::y[rip]
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L14:
        mov     DWORD PTR int test<Position>(int)::y[rip], 1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:guard variable for int test<Position>(int)::y
        call    __cxa_guard_release
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR int test<Position>(int)::y[rip]
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, `static const int y = x;` `y` is `const` means it is `non-mutable` and `static` is storage duration in program.

Compiler throws error if you try to modify `y` directly in subsequent statement and it is undefined behavior if tried to modify indirectly.

From c++ reference,

> **const object** - an object whose type is const-qualified, or a non-mutable subobject of a const object. Such object cannot be modified: attempt to do so directly is a compile-time error, and attempt to do so indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined behavior.